# LINQ to SQL class and staging vs. production

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a best practice question related to LINQ to SQL classes and having two SQL servers - production and development.

We have an MVC 4 project, which we publish on Azure Cloud. We have two connection strings that we automatically switch between. One for production instances and one when running on localhost, where we change the structures of the DB and test them. This part works great by using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal`

We have our DB context using LINQ to SQL classes but for now, we cannot figure out how to switch the DBML connection strings automatically as well. Or maybe have two DBMLs - one for production DB and one for the testing.

For example, we add a field in a table, refresh the DBML file, which we connect to the testing DB, and experiment with it. When we need to publish the project, we need to go and change the SQL structure on the production server first, change the connection string for the DBML manually, and then publish.

Is that the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should look into using [webdeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) coupled with [xdt transforms on your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).

For even more ease, instead of linq2sql, consider using [linq2entities/entity framework with migrations](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/), which allow you to automate the upgrading of the database in code so you don't have to manually update the schema on the deployment server.

With these 3 technologies you should be able to reduce the pain of deployment down to 2 or 3 clicks once you're all set up (which in itself might be quite painful).

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting you right. We use the Azure deployment that is built in the VS 2012. It is quite easy compared to what I know about WebDeploy.

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about Azure deployment, but I suspect that you're already part of the way there. Assuming you're using the "Publish" dialog for deployment, you should look into the "databases" tab which give you the option to create a publish profile with different connection strings.